# Conditional Distribution

Tags: distributions, conditional-probability

Let $D_{i}(\Sigma)$ be some distribution with $\Sigma$ being it's parameter. Let $X|\theta \sim D_{1}(\theta)$ , $\theta|\phi \sim D_{2}(\phi)$ . Can we say that $P(X|\theta,\phi)=P(X|\theta)$ because $\theta$ after all depends on $\phi$ ?

Comment: Are you familiar with graphical models? They can be helpful in these cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Your setting can be described with the following graphical model:

$$
\phi \rightarrow \theta \rightarrow X
$$

This means that $X$ is conditionally independent of $\phi$ given $\theta$. Some basic knowledge on graphical models will allow you to work this out yourself. See, for instance,

> Koller, Daphne, and Nir Friedman. Probabilistic graphical models: principles and techniques. MIT press, 2009.

You can also see it intuitively. Say $\theta=1,\phi=1$. The distribution of $X$ is completely determined by $\theta$ as $D_1(\theta)$. Now imagine $\theta=1,\phi=2$. Does that change the distribution of $X$? No. It is still $D_1(\theta)$. Once you know $\theta$, the value of $\phi$ is irrelevant for knowing the probabilty of each value of $X$.

Comment: In that case does the following relationship holds ? Why ? Why not ? $P\left( X \vert \theta \right) = \int P\left( X \vert \theta,\phi \right) P\left(\phi \right)d\phi$.

Comment: $\phi$ is known, so there is no need to marginalize. Conditioning on the known value of $\phi$, that integral is zero but at one point.

Comment: But if $\phi$ was a random variable , in that case the integral wouldn't be trivial . Is that correct ? Suppose $\phi \sim D_{3}(a,b)$ such that a and b is known. In that case, how would one calculate $P(X|\theta,\phi)$

Comment: If you condition on $\phi$, then you assume it is random. In the case you propose there is no difference. $\theta$ renders $X$ independent of anything above $\phi$ in the graph.